# Trying to use UDF .xll to parallelize Excel on HPC grid

Tags: excel, parallel-processing, user-defined-functions, hpc, xll

I'm looking to parallelize a Excel calculation on a HPC grid, I'm using Excel 2007 so I'm trying to multithread it through the UDF in a XLL because it is the only way (at least for 2007).

I would like to code the XLL in C# and as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665633/creating-an-excel-worksheet-function-udf-at-runtime-in-c-sharp) suggests I can use  [exceldna](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/documentation).

Yet I can't understand how should I multithread it. Do I have to re-write all the VBA function in C# while multithreading it ? Can I just create several threads, each one of them calling one VBA macro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) allows different approaches that you might find useful:

- you can make UDFs marked as 'thread-safe' to use [Excel's support for multithreaded calculation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687899.aspx) - in this case Excel controls the threading, and will call your UDFs concurrently from different threads,
- you can use the [asynchronous functions in Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Asynchronous%20Functions%20with%20Tasks) (possibly using the .NET 4 Task API) to start the work on the grid, and upon completion notify Excel to recalculate,
- you can use the [Reactive Extensions support](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Reactive%20Extensions%20for%20Excel) in Excel-DNA and build a calculation pipeline on the Rx library ,
- you can use the [support for Windows HPC clusters](http://excel-dna.net/2010/12/09/cluster-udf-support/) built into Excel 2010, using Excel-DNA to host the managed code in the client and on the cluster nodes.

In none of these cases would it make sense to call into Excel VBA - Excel will always ensure that the VBA code is running on Excel's main thread.

If your function code is in VBA, you might consider [using VB.NET for your Excel-DNA add-in](http://sysmod.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/from-vba-to-vb-net-using-exceldna/), instead of C# - it might make your move to .NET quite easy. You could also make a mixture of C# and VBA in your managed Excel-DNA add-in.

Comment: I'm going through your documentation and it seems to fit to my requirements but I have one question about the first option, how can I access the Excel file from the XLL? because it seems that there is only the .COM interface to communicate and I would like to invoke it from several threads. 
How is it possible to get access to the google group to see all the messages ?  
Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no restriction on viewing the posts on the Google group. When using Excel's multithreaded calculation, you should not be accessing the Excel file from the UDF, you just return a value. Excel takes care of the threading, you just register the function implementation.